# In Visual Studio is there a way to automatically add all resx language files to projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resx

In my C# project have multi language support using resx files. People do translation using external software and then doing pull request those resx files.

So I'm wondering is there a way to add those resx language files to projects automatically?

Example pull request: https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/pull/437 and have 58 resx files there for French and I need to add those to projects manually now.

Comment: You'll have to change the `.csproj` file at some point. It's just an XML file so you can write a little script that adds the entries of the pull request to your project file but at this point you might as well just add them manually with `add -> existing item`.

Comment: I thought maybe someone made extension or something like that for automate that .csproj editing.

Comment: A decent localization service does this for you.  They have to anyway since they need to verify that everything looks right and still fits.  Just give them a call and ask why they didn't do this.  And of course keep in mind that you get what you pay for.

Comment: check also Microsoft MAT: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matdev/2016/03/03/multilingual-app-toolkit-v4-0-update-1-is-available/

Answer (score 3):

You can manually edit the projects files to include all resx files using [wildcards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454.aspx), ex.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
```

That way, you just need to add the files to the project's directory (or any subdirectory).

Note that you will need to unload/load the project in Visual Studio (if currently is opened) when adding new files before the new files get noticed by Visual Studio.

EDIT: Since you want the resx files to be grouped with the Forms - which is done in MsBuild via the `DependentUpon` parameter - you will need to do the following for each form:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="MainForm*.resx">
  <DependentUpon>MainForm.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: I tried ```<EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />``` but it resulted this: http://i.imgur.com/vvGyZmp.png Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Jaex I'm not sure what the problem is that you have.

Comment: resx files should be sub of form like this: http://i.imgur.com/3c2klOH.png otherwise when we have more than 10 languages with countless files in project it will fill whole solution explorer and won't be good. Currently have around 60 files which require resx and multiply it with 10x languages then gonna have 600x resx files not inside form in solution explorer, it gonna be horrible.

Comment: @Jaex I put all my resources in a separate assembly, so I don't have that problem. Anyway, the solution is not quite as elegant, see my edit.